# Aliexpress web scraper not repeating

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, aliexpress

I'm a complete beginner but have a question about my code for web scraping products on aliexpress.

The problem is that I only get 1 result instead of all of them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://dutch.alibaba.com/products/uhf_rfid_label.html?IndexArea=product_en&page=1').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
producten = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='organic-list app-organic-search__list')
for product in producten:
    product_naam = product.find('p', class_ = 'elements-title-normal__content large').text
    jaren_actief = product.find('span', class_ = 'seller-tag__year flex-no-shrink').text
    print(f'''Product naam: {product_naam} ''')
```

How do I get the information of ALL the products?

Comment: Please add the responses you got when you try your approach. The more information you provide, better the community can understand your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will assume the information you want to get is the `title` of the product and the `price` as @Andrej_Kesley suggested in his answer.

Parsing the page as HTML, you can get only 8 products with Beautiful Soup as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://dutch.alibaba.com/products/uhf_rfid_label.html?IndexArea=product_en&page=1'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all('a', class_='elements-title-normal')
prices = soup.find_all('span', class_='elements-offer-price-normal__price')
num_products = len(products)

for i in range(num_products):
    print("{:<20} {}".format(prices[i].text, products[i].text))
```

Output:

```
US$ 0,02-US$ 0,10    Aangepaste Tag Sticker Labels Lange Bereik Goedkope Passieve Papier Roll Uhf Rfid Label
US$ 0,08-US$ 0,12    Magazijn & Asset & Productie Lijnmanagement Lange Afstand Alien H3 Chip Uhf Rfid Papier Label
US$ 0,78-US$ 0,85    Hopeland hot selling UHF RFID Animal Ear Tag mini uhf rfid ear tag 860 960MHz 5m reading range rfid label tag uhf
US$ 0,03-US$ 0,06    Factory Outlet Uhf Rfid Sticker/Label Met Chip
US$ 0,07-US$ 0,12    Long Range Goedkope Passieve Papier Roll Uhf Rfid Chip Label Tag Sticker
US$ 0,02-US$ 0,04    Groothandel Asset Tracking R6 Chip Uhf Papier Label Rfid Uhf Inventaris Labels Uhf Sticker
US$ 0,04-US$ 0,13    Aangepaste Tags Alien H3 9662 H9 9640/M4E Chip Long Range Passieve Uhf Rfid Tag/ Label/ Sticker
US$ 0,08-US$ 0,20    Full Color Afdrukken Hf/Uhf Passieve Papier Roll Smart Nfc Rfid Label/Sticker/Tag
```

Answer (score 1):

The information is about products (price, title, etc.) is embedded within the HTML page in Javascript (in actual HTML are rendered only 8 products). You can use `re`/`json` module to parse it. For example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

html_text = requests.get(
    "https://dutch.alibaba.com/products/uhf_rfid_label.html?IndexArea=product_en&page=1"
).text

data = re.search(r"window\.__page__data__config = (\{.*\})", html_text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)
# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for offer in data["props"]["offerResultData"]["offerList"]:
    print(
        "{:<20} {}".format(
            offer["tradePrice"]["price"], offer["information"]["puretitle"]
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
US $0.02-$0.10       Aangepaste Tag Sticker Labels Lange Bereik Goedkope Passieve Papier Roll Uhf Rfid Label
US $0.07-$0.12       Long Range Goedkope Passieve Papier Roll Uhf Rfid Chip Label Tag Sticker
US $558.00-$688.90   Hopeland 15 meter uhf rfid scanner r2000 rfid reader device uhf scanner handheld terminal multi tag uhf rfid scanner
US $0.03-$0.06       Factory Outlet Uhf Rfid Sticker/Label Met Chip
US $558.00-$688.90   Hopeland Draagbare Uhf Rfid Terminal ISO18000 6C Multi-Tag Management Uhf Rfid Handheld Reader 2D Barcode Uhf Rfid Terminal
US $0.03-$0.12       Gratis Monster Waterdichte Nfc 213 Long Range Passieve Uhf Rfid Tag/ Label/ Sticker
US $0.06             Printable Uhf Rfid Adhesive Label/Rfid Sticker Tag/Rfid Tag Voor Boeken
US $0.04-$0.13       Aangepaste Tags Alien H3 9662 H9 9640/M4E Chip Long Range Passieve Uhf Rfid Tag/ Label/ Sticker
US $0.04-$0.12       Gratis Sample Lange Range Passieve Uhf Rfid Tag/ Label/ Sticker
US $0.03-$0.06       Aangepaste Tags Long Range Uhf Rfid Inlay/Natte Inlay/Label/Sticker
US $0.08-$0.20       Full Color Afdrukken Hf/Uhf Passieve Papier Roll Smart Nfc Rfid Label/Sticker/Tag
US $0.08-$0.30       Rfid Uhf H3 9662 9654 Chip Inlay/Label/Sticker Tag (Asset Warehousing Tracking)
US $0.06-$0.08       50*50Mm Uhf Bibliotheek Boek Documenten Rfid Tag Sticker Label
US $0.09-$0.15       Alien H3 9662, Alien H3 9654, Alien H4 UHF RFID Inlay/Sticker/Label
US $0.06-$0.15       Gratis Sample Lange Bereik H3 Passieve Uhf Herbruikbare Rfid Sticker Tag Label Voor Asset Tracking
US $0.06-$0.13       Chenxin Apparel Management Custom Afdrukken Uhf Rfid Tag Rfid Kledingstuk Wassen Zorg Etiketten Voor Kleding
US $0.23-$0.25       Rfid Uhf Electronic Label Washing Cloth Washing Label Heat Resistant Rfid Label Flexible Clothing
US $0.09-$0.12       Hot Selling Passief Printable Inlay Sticker Tag Uhf Rfid Label Voor Magazijn Retail
US $0.03-$0.09       Global UHF RFID Label U7 RFID Tag Voor Bril Frames
US $0.06-$0.50       Factory price UHF RFID label/tag adhesive
US $0.06             LX-C90G Rfid Voorruit Tag Passieve Long Range Uhf Rfid Sticker Label Voor Auto Tol Tracking Voertuig Registratie Of Parking
```

Comment: Congrats on your 100K rep @Andrej Kesely.

Comment: @SIM Thank you. Looking forward for your 100k :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to know if the products are not rendered in just HTML and there is Javascript involved?

Comment: @ezzeddin If you do `print(soup.select('h4'))` you will see only few titles got printed. I searched for more title names in `print(soup)` and found them inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Interesting! Thanks!